# Curl Hangs on Particular Website on Ubuntu 16.04 but not 18.04 Even with Updated Version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, curl, installer-anaconda

Can anyone tell me why or how to diagnose why the following curl command hangs:

```
curl 'https://www.nasdaq.com/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
```

When run with a -v option this is the output (hangs on "old SSL session..."):

```
*   Trying 104.81.179.248:443...
* Connected to www.nasdaq.com (104.81.179.248) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Connecticut; L=Shelton; O=NASDAQ, INC.; CN=www.nasdaq.com
*  start date: Jun 15 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 20 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.nasdaq.com" matched cert's "www.nasdaq.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.nasdaq.com
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> DNT: 1
> Connection: keep-alive
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
```

Creating new AWS Ubuntu server 16.04 and 18.04 Amazon AMI instances and running the curl command hangs on 16.04 but not 18.04. On a different system running 14.04 I used Conda to update curl and openssl to a newer version than on the 18.04 system and it hangs despite the newer version.

Here is the output from running curl --version on the 14.04 system:

```
curl 7.71.1 (x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.71.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.9.0
Release-Date: 2020-07-01
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Here is the same thing run on the Ubuntu 18.04 AWS instance that works:

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Here's the same thing on another 18.04 system that uses Conda's curl and works correctly:

```
curl 7.63.0 (x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.63.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0
Release-Date: 2018-12-12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

I notice the two working systems have HTTPS-proxy listed as a feature, while the non-working one does not.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: did you check in Google `old SSL session ID is stale, removing` ? Or maybe you should ask on [curl issues](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues)

Comment: I did try googling that.  I saw mention of a curl bug involving that a number of years back, but it seems to have since been fixed, so I would have expected the problem to resolve when I updated curl if it were the same problem.  Asking on curl issues is a good idea though, I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to disable `ipv6`, e.g. on Ubuntu:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```